# Problem related to rendering line chat using MP android chat lib

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mpandroidchart, lib

## I want output in this format but I get in other format this image is clicked by zooming the chart in android phone but I want in blow format

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7RMV.jpg)

[I want to show data in above  I want output in this format but I get in other format] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jeqe2.jpg)

Comment: Add code snippet.

Comment: do you want to show the zoomed image by default?